# How do I store each detail section value in a separate Variable?

Tags: crystal-reports

Please check this image for details

## [image]

**Formula - @B**

```
If  {Command.Dept} in ["AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD"] and {@TOT}>0
Then
{@TOT}
```

So this should give me only values as follow

```
190
170
190
220
```

**Formula - @C**

```
If  {Command.Dept} in ["AAA-Bud","BBB-Bud","CCC-Bud","DDD-Bud"] and {@TOT}>0
Then  
{@TOT}
```

So this should give me only values as follow

```
150
200
230
260
```

Now I created another formula

**@Percent**

```
If ({@B} <> 0 AND {@C}<>0)
Then 
({@B}/{@C})* 100
```

When I plug `@Percent` formula on my repot I am getting error

> "Division By Zero" error.

So if I plug formula `@B`
I'm getting correct values for 1st 4 rows, but next 4rows `(AAA-Bud","BBB-Bud","CCC-Bud","DDD-Bud")` I'm getting 0.

For formula `@C` 1st 4 rows gives me `0` and next 4 rows `(AAA-Bud","BBB-Bud","CCC-Bud","DDD-Bud")` gives me correct values.

So how do I avoid those zeros so I can calulate correct percent values?

Comment: Could you share the formulas or code you've tried? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more pointers.

Comment: -Zac, Just added comments with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
If  {@C} >0
Then 
({@B}/{@C})* 100
```

Comment: I tried but still get same error "Division by Zero"